# Modify my POJO variable before setting it into the object of POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, annotations

I have a 5 POJO where the amount field is set with different variable names and while getting data from a third party i need to write a custom converter which will convert the amount from [paise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paisa) to rupees for specific variable.
Will custom annotation work?
I don’t want to override the setter method for each variable

I tried overriding the setter method but if new variables are introduced again setter will have to be overriden

Comment: Do you mean you have written five classes, all POJO classes?

Comment: Describe these classes briefly. Show contrived examples (don’t just dump your actual code here).

Comment: Please share the code here, so that we can understand the scenario and can answer